# Infinite source of healing

Tags: dnd-4e, healing

My revenant character just leveled up to 21st level and I picked the *ghostly vitality* feat. With that I noticed that as long as I can keep up healing myself, there is hardly anything that could actually kill me.

I am looking for a source that would allow me to regain at least one hitpoint every turn so that I could take advantage of the healing mechanics. (If under 0 HP any healing will start at 0.)

I could get crazy ammount of *potions of cure light wounds* and just drink one every turn but that relies on my abbility to be able to drink the potion.

My current character is lvl 21 Rogue (artful dodger) revenant - with Elf as a previous race. My paragon path is the *avenging haunt*. For my Epic destiny I chose *free soul*.

Is there any elegant way to achieve my goal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This depends on what level you are aiming to be or if you are making changes to your class. However, if you are staying at level 21 for now buffing your Death Saving Throw bonus extremely high and utilizing the *Unfailing Vigor* feat would be the simplest method, but can often rely heavily on your rolls.

> **Regain Hit Points:** When an adventurer is dying and receives healing, he or she is considered to have 0 hit points, and then regains hit points from the healing effect. If the healing effect requires the adventurer to spend a healing surge but he or she has none left, the healing still helps a bit: The adventurer’s hit point total is restored to 1.
>
> **Unfailing Vigor:** When you roll an 18 or higher on a death saving throw, you can spend a healing surge as if you had rolled a 20.

If you are looking long term, I would suggest looking into specific Epic Destinies. The *Arcane Sword* Epic Destiny gives you one option at Level 30.

> **Spellsword Perfection** *(30th level)*: Choose one swordmage encounter attack power that you know. You can now use that power as an at-will power rather than an encounter power.

If you take an Encounter such as *Bravado Strike* which lets you spend a healing surge whenever you hit, you can aim to hit with this move each round. This works even while you are out of healing surges. From there you can focus on items or feats that grant bonus hit points whenever you spend a healing surge, such as the *Ring of the Risen*

For an Elf Rogue Free Spirit, you only path is focusing on Death Saving throws and focusing specifically on a set of items and utilizing a great deal of money on potions. Here are the feats and items you can focus on.

> *Unfailing Vigor:* When you roll an 18 or higher on a death saving throw, you can spend a healing surge as if you had rolled a 20.
>
> *Disciple of Death*: +5 feat bonus to DST
>
> *Death Scorned*: You gain a +1 bonus to death saving throws.
>
> *Periapt of Recovery* - Gives +2 Item bonus to death saving throws. Any Level.
>
> *Potion of Spirit*: Level 30: gain a +6 power bonus to DSTs. 125,000 gp
>
> *Verve Armor*: Untyped +2 to DSTs. Any level armor.
>
> *Born of Shadow*: +1 Untyped bonus to DST, only works in dim light/darkness.

*Note: even with all these stacked bonuses you will need to avoid rolling a 1 on your Death Saving Throw and even then requires lots of funding for Potions of Spirit.*

Comment: Thanks for your breakdown. It made me think about DSTs and their effect on my character. I never really bothered with them since the _avenging haunt_ allows me to stay conscious until I *die* so I thought that doing TSTs is kind of pointless since our party healer throws some heal in my direction usually turn after I drop bellow 0HP. Does the 1 on DST you explicitly mentioned affect me in some diabolical way?

Comment: No, you will still make the DST. However, the assumption is that you have no other source of healing (ie Leader/Items/SecondWind) available and you need the '18+' roll to force yourself to spend a healing surge because you are dying. Otherwise the nat 1 will prevent you from spending the HS and going back to positive numbers, which means you no longer get to move around or act (by base).

Comment: There's no special effect that occurs if you roll a natural 1 on a DST, the only thing that matters is your total, not your die roll. If you've somehow got a high enough bonus to reach the requisite number on a 1, you still spend a surge. Therefore, I can't recommend putting Unfailing Vigor at the top of one's list (figuratively speaking), since it's not quite as good as an untyped +2 bonus to DSTs.

Comment: Also note: a 20+ on a DST doesn't raise you back to 1 HP if you're out of surges, unlike other ways of spending surges.

Comment: Well Unfailing Vigor does still give a boost to hit that cap, wherein there are no other feasible ways for this character to hit such numbers, hence the addition of the feat to get 2 points closer to spending the surge.

That being said after rereading the Dying rulings it does look like you would still need surges. I think the general consensus then would be that there is no way to feasibly stay alive in an 'infinite' manner with the OP's current Character, but rather get very close to never dying and making it very hard to be killed outright.

Answer (score 0):

Simplest solution: take or retrain to Initiate of the Faith or any other cleric specific multi-class feat. Then take the Adept Power feat to change a Level 5 or higher daily attack power into Consecrated Ground. While bloodied you regain HP equal 1 + your Charisma modifier in the zone at the start of your turn. This means that even if you fall unconscious you will regain consciousness in time to sustain the zone as a minor action.

Comment: Even though this is not a viable way for me to alter my character atm. it is a nice way I'll keep in mind for future character development. Thanks for pointing out this branch for me as I completely forgot about this option.

Comment: Yeah, it didn't sound like a good fit for your character's theme, but it's the easiest infinite healing trick I know, at least for midcombat. It's also still viable, even after the offensive potential of it got nerfed in the errata.